# Alternate color of groups of rows on a DBGrid

Tags: delphi, tclientdataset, tdbgrid, delphi-10.4-sydney

I want to alternate the colours of my grid by groups. My first try is doing this adding a GroupNumber to the ClientDataset (using the DENSE_RANK() function of SQL Server).

```
select dense_rank() over (order by Viatge) as GroupNumber, 
       Transports_v.* 
from Transports_v
where IdTransportista = :Id
order by 1
```

Now I can alternate colors on the grid using this code:

```
procedure TFFacturesTransportista.AEDBGrid1DrawColumnCell(Sender: TObject; const Rect: TRect; DataCol: Integer; Column: TColumn; State: TGridDrawState);
begin
  if Odd(QAlbaransPEndentsGroupNumber.Value) then AEDBGrid1.Canvas.Brush.Color := clInfoBk;

  AEDBGrid1.DefaultDrawColumnCell(Rect,DataCol,Column,state);
end;
```

It works well, but if I manually delete a row then I can have two consecutive even or odd groups, and they will be drawn with the same colour.

Is there a better way to check if the current record starts a new group ?.

Thank you.

Comment: Did you try JediVCL's UltimateDBGrid ?  `DBGrid1.AlternateRowColor := cl3DLight;` - and you have it.

Comment: You can just refresh the grid (i.e. reexecute the SELECT query) after you delete a row.

Comment: Alternatively you may **hope** to use `TDataSet.RecNo` by adding a *Calculated Field* that would proxy that value to your grid, then analyze it. 
Read about `AutoCalcFields` and friends and about http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/Data.DB.TDataSet.RecNo Granted, not every dataset would bother to implement .RecNo, but many do

Comment: @Arioch'The Groups are not defined by the record number.

Comment: @Arioch'The Thanks, but I don't want to alternate colours at every record, but only at every group of records defined by the field Viatge.

Comment: @Olivier Thanks, but it won't work for me, because I don't apply the changes until I leave the form, so re-executing the query would lose all those changes.

Comment: Then you should compute the group number on the client side, and recompute it after you remove a row from the `TClientDataset`.

Comment: @Olivier, yes, thanks, I will start doing this, although I hope someone knows a cleaner way than having to loop the entire dataset after every insertion/deletion.

Comment: Why isn't it "clean"? One way or another, you will need to traverse the dataset anyway to inspect the values of Viatge. The only optimization you can do is start from the record just before the one you deleted.

Comment: @MarcGuillot when you *invalidate* the DBGrid it will iterate through the `TDataSet` anyway, so don't be afraid to iterate, just think WHERE and HOW MUCH you do it. And yes, it is up to you HOW you compute the group or any other indicator attribute, and you can even compute the color itself (that would be bad old-skul approach), that is what **Calculated Fields** exist for

Comment: I would also consider using TVirtualTreeView in Report Mode :-)

Comment: @Arioch'The that's an interesting idea. :-)  I have done the group numbering on the client side, but I will give a try to a TreeView.

Comment: Just do not mistake stock Windows/VCL TreeVIew and VTV, those are VERY different if not totally. In particular, depending on your task, there may or may not be reason to load the whole datatset - it might be better to only load top-level and next-level nodes and load (N+1)th levels after user opens some Nth level node, if ever

Comment: Hi @Marc. I just thought it was worth mentioning that the JEDI TJvDBGrid we discussed in another Q&A the other day supports an alternate row color: wiki.delphi-jedi.org/wiki/JVCL_Help:TJvDBGrid.AlternateRowColor.

Comment: @MartynA even for groups he can use https://wiki.delphi-jedi.org/wiki/JVCL_Help:TJvDBGrid.OnGetCellParams much simpler, than mess with VCL standard custom-default drawing.  OTOH in one my project i used TJvUltimDBGrid and Unified-Interbase DB lib, and had to implement custom sorting, and ion the end i had to patch BOTH libs, or they created AV's on sorting, in between half-open dataset and half-initialized grid...

Answer (score 1):

There is no ‘magic’ function for what you want: use alternate color based on some field value (aka group) when the list is sorted on that field value/group.

But you could make your own list of groups (based on the dataset content) and then use the even/odd specification of the index of the group in that list to get the color.

When you delete rows, check to see if its the last row for that group and then delete the group from the list.
Other way around, when a record is added with a new group, add the new group to the group list.

Small note: the order of the groups in the list must be the same as the order in which the groups appear in the dataset!